# Counting Groups and Mobile users in Google Apps Domain

Tags: python-2.7, google-apps, gdata

I am trying to count count groups and mobile devices in a multi-domain Google apps domain using a python script. I am hoping to count the groups and mobile devices in their sub-domain.   I have used the information here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_all_groups_in_a_domain and I am not getting the information I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Provisioning API that you linked to is deprecated and should not be used for new development.

The new Admin SDK Directory API should allow you to perform these operations.

To get a list of all groups where the primary address is one of your subdomains, use the [groups.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/list) API call and specify the domain parameter with your subdomain.

To get a list of mobile devices associated with users in the subdomain, use the [mobiledevices.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/list) API call and specify customerId=my_customer as well as query=email:subdomain.com parameter.